# Trouble Running Leaks Instrument

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, simulator

I'm having trouble running the Leaks Instrument since installing the 3.0 SDK. An NDA disclaimer here I don't think this is a 3.0 SDK issue, just a configuration problem. So I'm looking for advice on configuring the tools in question not the 3.0 SDK per se.

Here’s the breakdown of the behavior I am seeing.

My Application is compiled to OS version 2.2. I can run it out of XCode in debug mode on the Simulator and Device running 2.2, 2.2.1, 3.0.

If I start it with Performance Tools -> Leaks, I get an error message from the OS,  “The application xxxx quit unexpectedly”, “Ignore, Report, Relaunch.” If I click “Ignore” one of two things will happen, either Leaks tells me it couldn’t attach, or Leaks stop responding to input and I have to Force Quit.  Interesting thing is the Simulator starts in 3.0 OS.

If I start Instruments Manually and attach to a running 2.2 Simulator it shows the same behavior.

If I attach Leaks to an iPhone Device it works.

It seems that once I launch Leaks my app won't run in the simulator until I do a new build.

Any ideas for getting my Simulator/Leaks/Xcode synced back up?

Thanks,
Geoff

Comment: I don't get the what an NDA has to do with this.

Comment: Apple doesn't like people talking about it's beta products. So the 3.0 Beta has an NDA on it. I'm not sure if it's as onerous as the original one, but I thought I'd point out that I wasn't asking for a discussion on the new SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across my own answer. I let the app build against the 3.0 SDK version then ran the Leaks Instrument. Now when I build the app against the 2.2 SDK the Leak Instrument will work.
It looks like a classic case of "jiggling the handle" to fix.