# Leaks Instrument not running in xcode 8.3.2

Tags: memory-leaks, xcode-instruments, xcode8

I have tried following the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671527/trouble-running-leaks-instrument).
All instruments work perfectly but leak instruments cause **this error:**

**An error occurred trying to capture Leaks data, Error retrieving leak information.**

I want to be able to use `Leak Instrument` without any errors. 
Image is also shown below.

Please help me. **Thanks in advance.**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Can you profile this project with other instruments, such as the Time Profiler instrument? Can you get the Leaks instrument to work on another project? You need to update your question and provide more information for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: For me, this happens when running my app with iOS 10.3. I tried running it on iOS 9 and it works perfectly.

Comment: I am using ios 10.3. It works perfectly in lower version.@AnnaFortuna

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me after updating the provisioning profile. It started working after restarting Instruments.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to Console view to know the specific reason

[image: Library not loaded]

For me the issue was caused by deleted Pod. Cleaning the project fixed that.

Comment: If anyone's wondering how to open the console, right-click on Run Issues.

Answer (score 2):

Try Checking your **provisioning** profile for **Profile Tool** on scheme of the app.

1. Go to Scheme editing window (just press **command shift and ,** (comma)).
2. Set Build Configuration to **Debug**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check that if you switch the Address Sanitizer.I close Address Sanitizer and then it works.
Edit Scheme -> Diagnostics

Comment: does not change anything

Comment: I was compiling using the command line and for me this was precisely what was causing the problem. When I stopped passing "-fsanitize=address" flag to the compiler this error went away and I was able to profile and find leaks and fix them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i upgrade the Xcode from 8.3.2 to 8.3.3 , it not works. Then I tried running it on true device , it works well.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

or

```
rm ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YouProject
```

close xcode restart your system then check it